# PHP: Best pratice of saving the role a user chose after login

Tags: php, session, object, cookies

I am using Symfony2 but this question is pretty general.

I want to login a user and right after the login, let him choose from a certain amount of "roles". These roles are objects in the database carrying a lot of configuration with them.

Question: What is the best practice of storing what role the User chose?

Session? But it's bad practice to store objects in sessions, isn't it?
Id of the role in the Session?
Id (or a hash of it) of the role in a cookie?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely store the session ID instead of the whole object. Specially if the object's data won't change from user to user. In fact, if the object's data won't change over time, you could potentially use one of several techniques to cache it.

Whether you use cookies or sessions to store the information depends on your requirements. If you need to store additional data (other than the ID of the role), and require such data to be safe from being edited, then you should consider using sessions, since they prevent the user from editing the stored data manually. Otherwise, using cookies is more efficient, since the server doesn't have to deal with all the hassle of session storing and retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

I would say store the ID of the role in the session, and retrieve the parts of the objects that you need whenever you need them (maybe all in one database call to save on that, if that's an issue). You have more control over sessions than over cookies, and users won't be able to turn them off.

Comment: Technically, users *can* turn sessions "off", since the reference to the session is stored as a cookie. However, they cannot (in most circumstances) edit the values of the specific variables tied to sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the role in session is a bad idea unless the roles never change (in which case you could as well hardcode them and just store role ID) or you are storing sessions in a way that allows you to update the role easily (database sessions for example).

Storing id/hash in cookie is just silly - why add another cookie if you can just store id/hash in session?

My recommendation: store role id in session. If you are worried about fetching it on every request you can always cache roles.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I think I will do it that way.